# What is the limit of income to lose social housing and social support in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands

I live with my family in the Netherlands.
My family is my wife and my daughter.

I receive "Uitkering" support from the state. I also have a flat under social housing.

Neither me nor my wife work.

If I work, what is the limit of income that I lose the social support?

Second, do I lose all the support at the same time? or things change according to my income? For example, the social housing, Zorgtoeslag (medical support), huurtoeslag (rent support).

Comment: Not 100% convinced this is an expat question. Rules do differ. For [zorgtoeslag](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/zorgtoeslag/content/maximaal-inkomen-voor-zorgtoeslag), the limit is close to 40k / year for a couple. For [huurtoeslag](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/huurtoeslag/content/maximaal-inkomen-huurtoeslag), it's a sliding scale to avoid threshold effects. What kind of *uitkering* are you getting?

Answer (score 4):

You will not be evicted from your house when you start earning more than the social housing limit but it might be possible your rent starts to go up faster if you are above that limit.

[Zorgtoeslag](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/zorgtoeslag/content/maximaal-inkomen-voor-zorgtoeslag) and [huurtoeslag](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/huurtoeslag/content/maximaal-inkomen-huurtoeslag) will go down when your income goes up, how much depends on how much your income goes up.

All this money is to help those who need it, if you can get a job that pays enough to lose the toeslagen you will earn more extra than making up the difference.